# Paper wallet creation, how safe is this approach?

Tags: backup, paper-wallet

I would like to create several paper wallets for different crypto currencies. Now I've read through a lot of manuals and I tried to install this Ubuntu version on a USB stick which I wanted to boot on my Mac computer. However after several tries I was still unsuccessful. So how safe would it be to:

1. Download all key generators, so I can use them offline
2. Disconnect from the internet
3. Generate the keys offline (in the "private" mode of Safari)
4. Not saving anything but directly connecting my computer to my printer via cable and print out the paper wallet
5. Delete all temporary files on my computer and on the printer
6. Reboot Mac
7. Only then connect again to the internet

Is this anyhow unsafe? Can someone intercept anything like this? Or find still some cached file or something after I connect back to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty safe to me. You should always consider that any machine that is connected to the internet at any time (and some that are not) can be compromised. The questions are, are you a likely target? Do you download or browse sites with questionable items (eg are you infected by something, or COULD you be)

Personally, i just run a VM, it's not connected to any network, i use the vmware client to reach it, i follow your steps 3 & 4 (although I use chrome) and then i reset the vm to a snapshot.